# Binary Stream With Unknown Byte-Width

Tags: code-challenge

**Context:**

> You are a cryptographer. You have stumbled upon a mysterious group of individuals, who present you with a challenge, which you must solve in order to join their secret society.

**Description:**

> You have been given a binary stream consisting of 3 byte sequences that have a random width (unchanging per-stream). This stream has the following properties:
>
> 1. The first two bytes in a sequence are randomly generated unsigned binary numbers.
> 2. The third byte is the sum of the first two bytes.
> 3. If the sum overflows, the carry-bit disappears (That is, it does not affect the first 2 bytes).
> 4. The bytes are big-endian.
> 5. The byte-width will always be between 3 and 16.

**Examples of potential streams**:

> A stream is an infinite series of 3 byte sequences, where the first 2 bytes are randomly generated for each sequence in the series.
>
> Byte-width = 5: 01001 01010 10011 10010 11101 01111 ... is a valid stream (without spaces, of course). 01001 + 01010 = 10011, and 10010 + 11101 = 01111 (after integer overflow).
>
> Byte-width = 10: 1100110011 0101010101 0010001000 ... is a valid stream. 1100110011 + 0101010101 = 0010001000 (after overflow).

**The Rules:**

> Write a program that consumes the binary stream, and outputs (with 100% certainty) the byte-width. This puzzle has two parts, efficiency and code-golf.
>
> Efficiency: Your score in this section is determined by the average number of bits your program must consume to make it's determination (after N>=1000 runs).
>
> Golf: Your score in this section is determined by the number of characters used in your code. This number does not include the scaffolding to generate the stream, includes/imports, or boilerplate. For example, in C/C++: int main(){ ONLY_THIS_COUNTS }.
>
> Your final score is equal to the multiplication of your scores in both sections. The lowest score wins.

Comment: @Sp3000 Added 2 examples for base 5 and base 10. Does that make any more sense?

Comment: @LivingInformation Suppose the program has read `110`. Can the program terminate and return bit width 1? If not, what is the maximum base, so the program can actually terminate?

Comment: @isaacg oops, I forgot to give a range on the bit-widths! The width will always be between 3 and 16, sorry about that.

Comment: In nearly all modern contexts the byte refers to an octet of bits. Perhaps you could use a word that causes less confusion? (word, grouping, chunk, etc).

Comment: Also, I assume we have to read the stream bit by bit, and can not skip elements?

Comment: Is the bit stream a *literal* bit stream in the form of random bytes that are shoved into stdin, or is it a string of characters, each representing a 1 or a 0? e.g. "1001110101100..." Also, is it necessary that we write a full program?

Comment: @BrainSteel you can treat it as either, but its probably easier to consume bit-by-bit if you use characters representing 1 and 0 (due to being unable to consume single bits in stdin, I believe you can only consume byte-by-byte in most environments, making consuming it one bit at a time difficult). When I have time, I'll be posting a python controller producing proper input for a program, but if you use another language, you'll need some way of generating streams.

Comment: Does the code for counting the bits that are consumed add to the golf score or are they part of the scaffolding/stream generation/boilerplate?

Comment: @nimi I would consider that part of stream generation, as the generation could be set up in such a way as to report the bit number in addition to the bit, on every consume. For example, in Python, you could return a tuple of (bit, bit_num).

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell 59.5 * 228 = 13566

```
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split
import Prelude.Unicode
import System.Random

findBW strm
 | i == 0    = (16, rest)
 | i < 3     = findBW rest
 | otherwise = (i, rest)

 where
 (bw,rest) = splitAt 4 strm
 i = sum $ zipWith ((*).(2^)) [0..] bw

mkStream i strm = first ++ second ++ sum ++ mkStream i rest
 where
 (first,tmp) = splitAt i strm
 (second,rest) = splitAt i tmp
 sum = reverse $ g (reverse first) (reverse second) 0

run 100000 reps _ = print $ (reps*16*3) / 100000
run n reps gen = do
 p validstream
 run (n+1) (reps+rep) gen2

 where
 (gen1,gen2) = System.Random.split gen
 (bytewidth, rndstream) = findBW $ randomRs (0::Int,1) gen1
 validstream = mkStream bytewidth rndstream
 rep = fst $ until(\(_,t)->sum[1|x<-h#t,x]<2)(\(n,s)->(n+1,tail#s))(1,f validstream)

main = do
 gen <- getStdGen
 run 0 0 gen

r=reverse
(#)=map
h=head
g[]_ _=[]
g(a:b)(c:d)e=mod(a+c+e)2:g b d(div(a+c+e)2)
c(m:n:o:p)=(g(r m)(r n)0≡r o):c p
f s=(scanl1(∧).c.(`chunksOf`s))#[3..16]
p=print.(3+).h.elemIndices True .(h#).until(\t->sum[1|x<-h#t,x]<2)(tail#).f
```

The average bits consumed in a run on 100,000 streams are around 59.3x / 59.4x , so I take 59.5 as the multiplier. For the golf part I count the characters of function `p` and it's helper functions, i.e. all characters beginning with `r=reverse` to the end. `p` is the function that analyses a bit stream and prints the byte-width.  Note: there are some unicode characters, all counting 1.

How it works: split the bit stream in chunks of 3 bits, 4 bits, ... 16 bits and check for validity. Repeat taking 3 of the chunks for every size until there's only one valid set. That means I consume 3*16 = 48 bits per repetition. Most of the time one ore two repetitions are enough.

Comment: Nice answer! Haskell is an interesting choice for this problem.